# Self referencing model in ASP.NET MVC 3 using Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, model, self-reference

I have a category class and it can reference itself(only one level up) as parent category.

When I retrieve the data using dbContext using Entity Framework, the parent relationship is not loaded. How do I go about achieving that?
Here is the class

```
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }       
    [Display(Name="Category Name")]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public int ParentCategoryID { get; set; }
    public virtual Category ParentCategory { get; set; }

}
```

when I retrieve all Category using dbcontext, the ParentCategory is null b/c it didn't join to another Category class with same ID.

Can anyone tell me how do I change db.Category.ToList() method so it also joins the parent child relation at the same time? Thanks

Comment: Can you put your mapping class?

Answer (score 2):

Try Like this

```
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }       

    [Display(Name="Category Name")]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public int? ParentCategoryID { get; set; }
    public virtual Category ParentCategory { get; set; }

}
```

And in your Context class,

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
    modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().
      HasOptional(e => e.ParentCategory).
      WithMany().
      HasForeignKey(m => m.ParentCategoryID);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ParentCategoryID` has to be nullable because the root category will not have a parent and EF needs to assign null to it.

```
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }       
    [Display(Name="Category Name")]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public int? ParentCategoryID { get; set; }
    public virtual Category ParentCategory { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Category
{

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Nom { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Category> SubCategory { get; set; } = new List<Category>();
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Category Parent { get; set; }
    public Guid? ParentId { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Can you add some additional information for why it works?