# Showing child in self referencing model in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, code-first, entity-relationship, self-reference

I'm developing an application on ASP.NET MVC 4 in this application I have a category and product tables, 
I've a self referencing model for holding categories :

```
public class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int? ParentId { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Category> Children { get; set; }


        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public byte[] RowVersion { set; get; }
    }
```

in my service layer I'm using this way to get list of categories (GetAll method) :

```
public class CategoryService : ICategoryService
{
        private readonly IDbSet<Category> _category;
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _uow;

        public CategoryService(IUnitOfWork uow)
        {
            _uow = uow;
            _category=uow.Set<Category>();
        }

        public IList<Category> GetAll()
        {
            return _category.Include(x => x.Parent)
                .ToList();
        }
}
```

below is my my action method for passing model to partial view :

```
public ActionResult Categories()
        {
            var query = _categoryService.GetAll();
            return PartialView("_Categories",query);
        }
```

PartialView :

```
@model IEnumerable<SarbarzDarb.Models.Entities.Category>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    if (item.Parent != null)
    {
    <li class="dropdown">
        @Html.ActionLink(item.Parent.Name, actionName:"Category", controllerName: "Product", routeValues: new {Id=item.Id, productName=item.Name.ToSeoUrl() }, htmlAttributes:null)


    </li>
}
}
```

everything is fine and with above code it shows me parent category that stored in database, my data in category table is like this :

```
Id  Name        RowVersion  ParentId
--  ------      ----------  --------
1   Parent1     NULL        1
2   Parent2     NULL        2
3   Child1      NULL        NULL
4   child2      NULL        NULL
5   child3      NULL        NULL
```

now my question is that How can I show children objects in partial view too.
Should I use another column in my category table for specifying relation between parent and child? for example in above table how can I find out that what is parent for child 2 or child3 and so on? or which parent is parent of child1?
below code is configuration for my category model:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
           .HasOptional(c => c.Parent)
           .WithMany(c => c.Children)
           .HasForeignKey(p => p.ParentId);
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
```

I've searched a lot for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024928/self-referencing-model-in-asp-net-mvc-3-using-entity-framework) but I didn't get my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem, I should have changed code inside `GetAll` method in `CategoryService` this way :

```
public IList<Category> GetAll()
        {

            return _category.Where(category => category.ParentId == null)
                            .Include(category => category.Children).ToList();
        }
```

Then In my partial view :

```
@model IEnumerable<SarbarzDarb.Models.Entities.Category>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{

    <li class="dropdown">
        @Html.ActionLink(item.Name, actionName: "Category", controllerName: "Product", routeValues: new { Id = item.Id, productName = item.Name.ToSeoUrl() }, htmlAttributes: null)

        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            @foreach (var child in item.Children)
            {
                <li class="dropdown">
                    @Html.ActionLink(child.Name, "Category", "Product", new { Id = child.Id, productName = child.Name.ToSeoUrl() }, null)
                </li>
        }
        </ul>
    </li>

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be a little bit differ to my mind. `ParentID` shouldn't be equal to `id`. It makes no sense. So if child may have only one parent, then you may change your table as follows:

```
Id  Name        RowVersion  ParentId
--  ------      ----------  --------
1   Parent1     NULL        NULL
2   Parent2     NULL        NULL
3   Child1      NULL        1
4   child2      NULL        1
5   child3      NULL        2
```

Now to get children of Parent1 you just need to make query like following. But for your PartialView you don't even need this query.

```
var children = db.Categories.Where(g=>g.Id == 1);
```

Then you may modify your View:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{

    <li class="dropdown">
        @Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Category", "Product", new {Id=item.Id, productName=item.Name.ToSeoUrl() }, null)
        <ul>
       @foreach (var child in item.children)
        {
            <li class="dropdown">
        @Html.ActionLink(child.Name, "Category", "Product", new {Id=child.Id, productName=child.Name.ToSeoUrl() }, null)
           </li>
         }
        </ul>

    </li>
 }
```

If your child categories may have more, then one parent, you may create join table like this:

```
ParentId  ChildID 
--        ------      
2          3
1          3
1          4
2          5
1          5
```

Comment: thanks, what about my category class? Is it OK? i mean about its design and its configuration when model creating.

Comment: @SirwanAfifi To my mind it's absolutly normal. Should work, as for me.